# Files showing up in terminal run, not in browser

Tags: php

I'm trying to list the files in a directory, but only the HTML portion of the page shows up in my browser. When I run the page through the PHP terminal interpreter, all the files are listed with the proper HTML tags.

files.php:

```
<html><head><title>Title</title></head>

<body>

<?php
   $currentdir = '/home/tim/Documents/Web/';
   $dir = opendir($currentdir);
   echo '<ul>';
   while ($file = readdir($dir)){
      echo "<li>$file</li>";
   }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP is installed, all my other .php pages have loaded just fine.

Comment: Do you see the <ul> tag in the output? 

Check the return value of opendir() and readdir(), don't just assume they were successful.

Comment: Turns out, the folder didn't have access permissions. Changing them so that everyone could view the folder allowed the files to show up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your webserver does parse PHP files, I would suggest putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your script. That will force PHP to spit out any error which may have resulted from path/permission problems, thereby helping you to debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

PHP should also be available to webserver and .php extension should be associated with php. Depends on the webserver you use, there are different instructions on how to install and enable php.